# create user in azure ad with ansible

Tags: ansible, azure-active-directory, office365

Im using the Azure.azcollection.azure_rm_aduser module in ansible to create a user in AzureAd.
It gives me the Error:

```
FAILED! => {
"changed": false, 
  "msg": "failed to get ad user info Insufficient privileges to complete the operation."
}
```

Im trying to authenticate via service principal, i gave my SP the application permissions User.ReadWrite.All and  Directory.ReadWrite.All.

It works as intended with Azure Login with my User, but it has MFA activated and i want to run the script in a container.
It also works with Microsoft Graph.

edit:
The Code i use:

```
    - name: Create user
  azure.azcollection.azure_rm_aduser:
    user_principal_name: "{{ principal_name }}"
    state: "present"
    account_enabled: "True"
    display_name: xxx
    password_profile: Xxxxx12#
    subscription_id: "{{ subscription_id }}"
    client_id: "{{ client_id }}"
    secret: "{{ secret }}"
    tenant: "{{ tenant }}"
```

Comment: Can you share the code, what you have tried to create an Azure AD user?

Answer (score 0):

I faced  the same problem,  use PIM.

You have to assign an permanent role to your service principal in Azure AD PIM for User Administration.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please phrase this as an explained conditional answer, in order to avoid the impression of asking a clarification question instead of answering (for which a comment should be used instead of an answer, compare https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead ). For example like "If your problem is ... then the solution is to .... because .... ."